# Unable to call gnome-terminal command in my C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, gnome-terminal

```
char *mycmd = "gnome-terminal --profile 'me' -e '/usr/bin/programA --file/usr/bin/config/myconfig.ini --name="programA" --loggingLevel=1'";
popen(mycmd, "r");
```

Error on 1st line: error: `expected ';' before 'Node'`

I know this is because of the "" for `--name`

Is there anyway to get this command to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the double quotes :

```
char *mycmd = "gnome-terminal --profile 'me' -e '/usr/bin/programA --file/usr/bin/config/myconfig.ini --name=\"programA\" --loggingLevel=1'";
```

Comment: Your second option won't work because the `-e '/usr/bin/programA --file/usr/bin/config/myconfig.ini --name='programA' --loggingLevel=1'` section is already wrapped in single quotes. You'd need to escape either type.